# nginx load balancing without upstream

Tags: nginx

I know how to load balance using upstream and proxy_pass but I am curious if it's possible to load balance without using upstream, just with if/else or map (some round robin if possible or random).

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to balance w/o upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx do the load balance only in the standard way they have provided such as follows:-

The round-robin method

The least_conn method

The ip_hash method

The generic hash method

The least_time method (NGINX Plus)

For more details refer [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/)